# Can variables be intervals (as3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, intervals

So, I'm trying to create an infinite loop with variables, like pong in a way, you hit the ball and it goes back, left, right, left, right again and again.It works, but every time it keeps getting faster and faster, and I know why.You'll probably find the reason in the code, but every time I set a new interval, I can't clear it, because it's not assigned to a variable.Anyway, what I want is the same speed every time, not getting faster and faster, is there a way around this or if so could you please suggest an alternative? Thank you!

```
import flash.events.Event;

var badbee1right:uint = setInterval (beebad1right, 100);
function beebad1right():void {
    beebad1.x+=15;
}

var badbee1left:uint = setInterval (beebad1left, 100);
clearInterval(badbee1left);
function beebad1left():void {
    beebad1.x-=15;
}

leftbadbeewall.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, leftbadbeewallhit);
function leftbadbeewallhit(e:Event) {
    if(beebad1.hitTestObject(leftbadbeewall)) {
        beebad1.x+=7;
        clearInterval(badbee1left);
        clearInterval(badbee1right);

    }
}

rightbadbeewall.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rightbadbeewallhit);
function rightbadbeewallhit(e:Event) {
    if(beebad1.hitTestObject(rightbadbeewall)) {
        clearInterval(badbee1right);
        bee.x-=7;
        clearInterval(badbee1left);
    }
}
```

Comment: While it's a nice idea using multiple setIntervals, and multiple enterFrame handlers it is computationally overkill. Generally speaking when doing programatic animation you will want to use a single as3 Timer object to create a drawing loop, and execute all of your logic there. 100 ms is a decent interval to start with. Instead of encapsulating each animation subject's drawing logic in listener functions you will get more traction encapsulating the logic in a class and updating instances of that class (or classes) in the drawing loop.

Answer (score 0):

That code doesnt make alot of sense! Also 2 frameHandlers is always a bad idea. Why not check and set the direction with a boolean!?
something like this: (not testet)
this snippet asumes you have the instances badbee1, leftbadbeewall & rightbadbeewall
on the stage

```
var goingRight:Boolean = true;
var speed:uint = 15;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);

function enterFrame(e:Event):void{

    if(goingRight)
        badbee1.x += speed;
    else
        badbee1.x -= speed;

    if(beebad1.hitTestObject(leftbadbeewall))
        goingRight = true;

    if(beebad1.hitTestObject(rightbadbeewall))
        goingRight = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad idea to plan ahead for y-axis motion as well as x. Try the code below by calling moveBee() from your enterframe method. You will have to use your own values for _beeBounds. Play around with _beeDelta, which is the amount badbee will move with each frame. The code will do the same thing if you hit a left/right limit -- it will multiply the x delta by -1 and send the bee in the opposite direction. The same applies for y values. If you don't want y-axis motion, you can set _beeDelta.y to zero.

```
private var _beeBounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
private var _beeDelta:Point = new Point(15,5);

private function moveBee():void{
  badbee.x += _beeDelta.x;
  badbee.y += _beeDelta.y;

  if(badBee.x > _beeBounds.right || badbee.x < _beeBounds.left){
    _beeDelta.x *= -1;
    badbee.x += _beeDelta.x; //optional correction. prevents badbee from being out of bounds for a frame.
  }
  if(badBee.y > _beeBounds.top || badbee.y < _beeBounds.bottom){
    _beeDelta.y *= -1;
    badbee.y += _beeDelta.y;
  }
}
```